# Nested ImageMagick commands

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

How would I append the following commands into a single command for ImageMagick?

```
convert -size 1024x1024 xc:none -draw "roundrectangle 0,0,1024,1024,40,40" png:- | convert AppStore.png -matte - -compose DstIn -composite Logo@3x.png
convert -resize 50% Logo@3x.png Logo@3x.png
convert -resize 50% Logo@3x.png Logo@2x.png
convert -resize 50% Logo@2x.png Logo.png
```

Comment: You didn't give us `Appstore.png`, so your example isn't minimal and complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably want something like this:

```
convert AppStore.png -matte                                                 \
   \( -size 1024x1024 xc:none -draw "roundrectangle 0,0,1024,1024,40,40" \) \
   -compose DstIn -composite -resize 50% -write MPR:basic                   \
   \( MPR:basic -resize 50% -write Logo@2x.png +delete \)                   \
   \( MPR:basic -resize 25% -write Logo.png    +delete \)                   \
   Logo@3x.png
```

Or this if you want to avoid the MPR (Memory Program Register):

```
convert AppStore.png -matte                                                 \
   \( -size 1024x1024 xc:none -draw "roundrectangle 0,0,1024,1024,40,40" \) \
   -compose DstIn -composite -resize 50%                                    \
   \( +clone -resize 50% -write Logo@2x.png +delete \)                      \
   \( +clone -resize 25% -write Logo.png    +delete \)                      \
   Logo@3x.png
```