# imagemagick nested gravity centering

Tags: imagemagick, centering

I am trying to composite two images with gravity, and then position them within a larger image at a geometry.

When I try

```
magick  -size 1045x837 xc:blue   \( -size 345x437 xc:red \( -size 275x417 xc:white -resize 345x437 -gravity center \) -composite \) -geometry +26+53 -composite test-y.png
```

I get

[image]

and when I do

```
magick  -size 1045x837 xc:blue   \( -size 345x437 xc:red \( -size 275x417 xc:white -resize 345x437  \) -composite  \) -geometry +26+53 -composite test-x.png
```

I get

[image]

I think this involves `clone` and related, [maybe similar to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35522677/263858), but I just can't find the combo.

What do I need to do, to get the white centered within the red, and geometrically placed in the upper-left corner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what you want, but I think you are falling foul of the fact that `-gravity` is a *"setting"*. As such, it remains set until changed, so you probably want this, where I reset the gravity to `NorthWest` before the final composite:

```
magick  -size 1045x837 xc:blue   \( -size 345x437 xc:red \( -size 275x417 xc:white -resize 345x437 -gravity center \) -composite \) -gravity northwest -geometry +26+53 -composite  result.png
```

[image]

You might find `-extent` a simpler way to fill out the white to a given size using a red background:

```
magick  -size 1045x837 xc:blue \( -size 275x417 xc:white -resize 345x437 -background red -gravity center -extent 345x437 \) -gravity northwest -geometry +26+53 -composite  result.png
```

Comment: The concept that this is a *setting*, vs other properties, was the missing link!  Also, while `-extant` works better in this gedanken, I don't think that it works in my live case, where I am using images that need to remain in-proportion as they're scaled.